# ykeys null in morris line chart

Tags: javascript, null

I have 3 ykeys parameters and sometimes one or other ykey value will be null. Eventhough I have one null ykey, I should get line chart for other ykeys. But now that's not happening. I'm getting blank chart and getting 'SVG' error.

Kindly help on this, here is what I tried so far:

```
new Morris.Line({ element: 'divname',
                  data: [ { year: '2008', a: '',b:'10',c:'20'},
                          { year: '2009', a: '',b:'15',c:'25'},
                          { year: '2010', a:'',b: '5' ,c:'10'} ],
                  xkey: 'year',
                  ykeys: ['a','b','c'],
                  labels: ['A','B','C'] });
```

-- in this case I need line chart for b and c values. But I'm getting SVG error with empty chart

Comment: welcome @praveen, could you provide some code, you'll get better feedback that way :)

Comment: @Adriean.                                                        new Morris.Line({
  element: 'divname',
  data: [
    { year: '2008', a: '',b:'10',c:'20'},
    { year: '2009', a: '',b:'15',c:'25'},
    { year: '2010', a:'',b: '5' ,c:'10'}
  ],
  xkey: 'year',
  ykeys: ['a','b','c'],
  labels: ['A','B','C']
});   -- in this case I need line chart for b and c values. But I'm getting SVG error with empty chart

Comment: thanks, I add it to your question. next time edit your comment to include it yourself :)